# How to get the selected index path for UIImageView object present on a UITableVIewCell of UITableView?

Tags: ios, uiimageview, tags, nsindexpath, uiatableview

I have a tableview with custom tableView cell present in it.
I have placed a UIImageview on custom tableViewCell. When i press or touch the imageView, i want to download some images from url, on the basis of selected index, which i am going to pass it(selectedIndex) as a string in the url.

What happens is when i first touch the image view, i am not getting the selected index path. But when i first select the cell and then i press the image view, at that time i get the selected index path. I searched it on the internet, but didn't found any appropriate solution. Here below is my code where i assign a UILongPressRecognizer to the UIImageView, in cellForRowAtIndexPath method.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


cell.imgvDownload.tag=indexPath.row;
    singleTap = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapDetected12)];

    [cell.imgvDownload setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    [singleTap.delegate self];
    [singleTap setMinimumPressDuration:0.01f];
    [cell.imgvDownload addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];

return cell;
}
```

The problem is that UIImageview is to able to get the selected index path  for the row selected. But if  i first select any cell(row) from tableView and then press the UIImage view, i get the index.
Can anyone please tell me what wrong am i doing here. Any help is appreciated.

EDIT

I have slightly changed my code. Instead of using UIImageView and UILongPressGestureRecognizer, i am using a UIButton. And on press of that button i am trying to get the index path of the cell on which the button is present. Here Below is my new code.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

cell.btnDownload.tag=indexPath.row;
return cell;
}
```

and the button press action method is-

```
-(IBAction)btnDownload:(id)sender{

UIView *sourceView = [sender view];
if ([sourceView isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
    NSLog(@"row is %ld", sourceView.tag);
}
```

and on did select method i am storing the selected index path like this-

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
selectedIndex =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",[[_shopDArrayFetched objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]valueForKey:@"ctid"],[[_shopDArrayFetched objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]valueForKey:@"scid"]];
    NSLog(@"selectedIndex %@",selectedIndex);
}
```

and i want this index on my button click which i am not able to get.
 Also the app is crashing on the line-  UIView *sourceView = [sender view]; saying -[UIButton view]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
Any help or suggestions is appreciated.

Comment: If you want just tap then why are you using `UILongPressGesture` instead of `UITapGesture`?

Comment: i did tried it using UITapGesture, But no change.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed you have restore indexPath.row in imageView, so all you need to do is in `@selector(tapDetected12)` get indexPath.row from imageView. Before you do this, there is one more thing to do: replace you `@selector(tapDetected12)` with `@selector(tapDetected12:)` the new parameter is a UIGestureRecognizer instance, from it you can get image view that user long pressed via `UIGestureRecognizer`'s property `@property(nullable, nonatomic,readonly) UIView *view`. 
**Sample**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"reuseid" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.textLabel.text = self.datas[indexPath.row];
    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"someicon"];
    cell.imageView.tag = indexPath.row;
    UILongPressGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapDetected12:)];

    [cell.imageView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    [singleTap.delegate self];
    [singleTap setMinimumPressDuration:0.01f];
    [cell.imageView addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];

    return cell;
}

- (void)tapDetected12:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {
    UIView *sourceView = gestureRecognizer.view;
    if ([sourceView isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]]) {
        NSLog(@"row is %ld", sourceView.tag);
    }
}
```

**Snapshot**
You can notice I select row 6 first(label text is 07), when I tap row 3(label text is 04), NSLog output is `3`
[image]

Comment: still not able to get the index path for image view on a particulate UITableViewCell. Help me

Comment: @ammy1 Pls update more detail otherwise I can not help you. What's value   of `sourceView.tag`? and what kind of `[sourceView class]`

Comment: @ammy1 why `UIView *sourceView = [sender view];`? `sender` is an instance of your `btnDownload`, so using `UIView *sourceView = (UIView *)sender;` instead of `UIView *sourceView = [sender view];`. Another question, what kind of class is sender you expected?

Comment: I don't know much about the sender classes as i am new to iOS.  what i am doing is for this tableview i have assigned some variables to each row (cell) in table view. As i select any row in the table view, i get that particular value for that cell. For example-if i select 1st cell, i get the selected index as-1001. if i select 2nd cell i get the selected index as 1002...and so on. These values i am not able to get on click on button present on tableview cell. What should i be doing here?

Comment: @ammy1 I had implement your requirement in sample code. And another answer from Diana Prodan is also correct I have no idea what is puzzling you

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
    {
          // ...

          cell.imgvDownload.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
          UITapGestureRecognizer *imageTapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self  action:@selector(imageTap:)];
          [imageTapRecognizer setDelegate:self];
          [cell.imgvDownload addGestureRecognizer:imageTapRecognizer];
          cell.imgvDownload.tag = indexPath.row;

          return cell;
    }

    - (void)imageTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)sender
    {
          UIView *view = sender.view;
          NSLog(@"%ld", (long)view.tag); //By tag, you can find out where you had tapped.
    }
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but still not working. Please help me out.